# IIS 7 Logs Vs Custom

Tags: iis, iis-7

I want to log some information about my visitors.  Is it better to use the IIS generated log or to create my own in an SQL 2008 db.

I know I should probably provide more information about my specific scenario, but I'd like just generally, pros and cons of either proposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what information you want to analyse.

If you're doing aggregations and rollups then you'd want to pull this data into a database for analysis. Pulling your data into a database will give you access to indexes and better querying tools.

If you're doing infrequent one-off simple queries then [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) might be sufficient for your needs. However you'll be constantly scanning unindexed flat files looking for data which is I/O intensive.

But as you say, without knowing more about your specific scenario it's hard to say what would be best.

Comment: Its good enough to know that IIS stores stuff in flat files.  I'd like to be able to query data, sooo custom logging to a DB it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can add additional information to the IIS logs from ASP.NET using `HttpResponse.AppendToLog`, additionally you could use the [**Advanced Logging Module**](http://www.iis.net/download/AdvancedLogging) to create your own logs with custom filters and custom data including data from Performance Counters, and more.